# C# http(s) GET request problems

Tags: c#, http, https, get, request

Somehow I believe I am not doing my HTTP requests correctly.

This site:

https://www.bintube.com/login/

Has 2 html input fields with names:

```
ctl00$main$Login1$UserName and ctl00$main$Login1$Password
```

The HTML code for the submit button is:

```
<input type="submit" name="ctl00$main$Login1$LoginButton" value="Login" onclick="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;ctl00$main$Login1$LoginButton&quot;, &quot;&quot;, true, &quot;Login1&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, false))" id="ctl00_main_Login1_LoginButton" />
```

Strangely enough, it is not contained within form tags and unfortunately the onclick stuff is a black box for me.

So in order to get the right parameters for the GET request, I have to use Fiddler, since I do not know how the GET URL parameters (timestamp and hash) are generated. It looks something like this in fiddler:

```
http://support.bintube.com/access/remote/?name=myname&email=myemail%40gmail.com&external_id=myexternal_id&organization=BinTube.com&timestamp=1353061816&hash=2372492438924389243
```

However this URL is totally different from the former mentioned URL https://www.bintube.com/login/ (SSL). So I do not know if I missed anything until it jumped to http://support.bintube.com/ (that is what Fiddler shows me) and, also, I always have to use Fiddler to give me the URL for my C# code, in order to login with my code. Ideally, my code would figure everything out on it's own so I do not have to use Fiddler.

My code is:

```
var cc = new CookieContainer();
List<string> paras = new List<string>();
string url;
string html;
// data copied from Fiddler, (changed some of it of course):
paras.Add(String.Format("{0}={1}", "name", HttpUtility.UrlEncode("myname")));
paras.Add(String.Format("{0}={1}", "email", HttpUtility.UrlEncode("myemail")));
paras.Add(String.Format("{0}={1}", "external_id", HttpUtility.UrlEncode("myexternal_id")));
paras.Add(String.Format("{0}={1}", "organization", HttpUtility.UrlEncode("BinTube.com")));
paras.Add(String.Format("{0}={1}", "timestamp", HttpUtility.UrlEncode("1353061816")));
paras.Add(String.Format("{0}={1}", "hash", HttpUtility.UrlEncode("2372492438924389243")));
url = "http://support.bintube.com/access/remote/" + "?" + paras.Aggregate((x, y) => x + "&" + y);
var req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
Console.WriteLine(url);
req.CookieContainer = cc;
req.Method = "GET";
req.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
// also copied from Fiddler
req.Host = "support.bintube.com";
req.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.64 Safari/537.11";
req.KeepAlive = true;
req.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8";
//req.Headers["Accept-Encoding"] = "gzip,deflate,sdch"; //<- this give gibberish response, why?
req.Headers["Accept-Language"] = "de-DE,de;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4";
req.Headers["Accept-Charset"] = "ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3";
HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
cc.Add(resp.Cookies);
//rewrite cookies for further requests (found that somewhere, but did not help)
string ckheader = cc.GetCookieHeader(req.RequestUri);
cc.SetCookies(new Uri("http://www.bintube.com/"), ckheader);
StreamReader r = new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream());
html = r.ReadToEnd();
```

The code works. Sometimes it stops working then I have to get new GET parameters from Fiddler, which is ugly design and I am not happy about it at all. The second, bigger, problem is I cannot use

```
https://www.bintube.com/search/ (requires login for results)
```

with my recieved cookies. The recieved cookies (from the first request) are _zendesk_session and _zendesk_shared_session cookies, nothing important (googled it). So somehow I believe I don't get the right cookie to advance further.

Maybe someone has some hints for me on why I am failing so badly?

Comment: 1. "Strangely enough, it is not contained within form tags" - yes it is 2. Look in that blackbox - like most ASP.NET button clicks, it's doing a POST not a GET